# how to remove undefine variable error in scilab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, syntax-error, scilab

```
im=imread('C:\Users\user\Desktop\DIP LAB\PRACTICAL IMG.jpg')
[row col byt]=size(im);
a=im(:,:,1); 
b=im(:,:,2); 
c=im(:,:,3); 
a=double(a); 
b=double(b); 
c=double(c); 
for x=1:1:row 
for y=1:1:col 
new(x,y)=(a(x,y)+b(x,y)+c(x,y))/3; 
new1(x,y)=0.3*a(x,y)+0.59*b(x,y)+0.11*c(x,y); 
end 
end 
figure(1) 
imshow(uint8(im)) 
figure(2)
imshow(uint8(new)) 
figure(3) 
imshow(uint8(new1))

Undefined variable: new1
```

I was performing a practical of digital image processing in Scilab, Converting a color image into a grey level image. the program executed completely at first but after 2 executions it is throwing an error as "undefined variable new1". can anyone please tell me where it is going wrong?

Comment: Why the C tag? Doesn't look like C code.

Comment: You need to provide more information ie the error output copy and paste, things you have tried and a bit more detail about what the line in question is suppose to achieve. Also what you have tried and what the results of what you have tried so far. As it stands no one is likely to read your code and try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you had some border effect since you don't intialize your a,b,c matrices and run your script for different image size. Retype your script as follows (without using loops) and give it a try:

```
im=imread('C:\Users\user\Desktop\DIP LAB\PRACTICAL IMG.jpg')
a = im(:,:,1); 
b = im(:,:,2); 
c = im(:,:,3); 
a = double(a); 
b = double(b); 
c = double(c); 
new = (a+b+c)/3; 
new1 = 0.3*a+0.59*b+0.11*c; 
figure(1) 
imshow(uint8(im)) 
figure(2)
imshow(uint8(new)) 
figure(3) 
imshow(uint8(new1))
```